# how to send the user data dynamically from html to angularjs function and from there to controller

Tags: javascript, html, spring, angularjs

below is my html

```
<div class="container page" ng-controller="Homectrl" style="margin-top:8px;">
<form id ="form" novalidate class="simple-form" >
<input type="text" ng-model = user.name name="id"/>
<button ng-click="init(user)">update</button>
</form>
</div>
```

and js

```
$scope.init = function(user) {
            alert(user); }
```

I am trying to take the user input to the query dynamically through the controller.
So I tried to get the value in angular js page but I am getting object object in alert. Please suggest me how to take the user input to the angular js and from the controller dynamically, My sql query is `Select * from customer where id =?` , so I need to replace the question value with user input, using angular js and spring controllers.

Thanks

Comment: Of course you get object in alert, because you show the user object, not it's name. Try user.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input value is already in sync with your model, since you use `ng-model`. Therefore you don't need to pass it to the init function. You can try something like this to alert user name:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container page" ng-controller="Homectrl" style="margin-top:8px;">
  <form id="form" novalidate class="simple-form" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="id"/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="init()" value="Update"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',[]).
  controller('Homectrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.init = function() {
      alert($scope.user.name);
    }

  });
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JiWFnL6EFthfRjeeJocu?p=preview

If you want to make a REST call to some server-side API consider look into [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) or [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: Thanks, how to send the user.name to the controller using $http

Comment: Is this correct ---> method: 'post',
        url: "rest/welcome/home",
        data :user.name,
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: 'application/json'

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. You are already able to pass the user object in the init function in the controller. Since you are showing the object as alert, you are able to see it only as `[object, object]`.
You can instead use `console.log(user)` to see the changes in the function. There you will see the user object.
Or `alert(user.name)` or `alert(JSON.stringify(user))`. The last one will show all properties and values in quotes.